How to forward a lambda function to an underlying std::thread constructor in order to execute it in a separate thread?
Given a path, a file watcher is routinely checking its availability (in case of creation/deletion) or timestamp (in case the file exists and its contents have been modified). The code below (take from here) is work in progress and I am adapting it to also support single file (the original code supports multiple where the given path is a directory).
class FileWatcher {
public:
    std::string m_path;
    std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli> m_delay;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_watcher_thread;

    FileWatcher(std::string path, std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli> delay);

    void start(const std::function<void(std::string, FileStatus)>& action);
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> m_paths;
    bool m_running = true;

    bool contains(const std::string& key);
};

FileWatcher::FileWatcher(std::string path, std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli> delay) : m_path{ path }, m_delay{ delay } {
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
    auto const p = std::filesystem::path(m_path);
    if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p))
    {
        m_paths[p.string()] = std::filesystem::last_write_time(p);
    }
    else if (std::filesystem::is_directory(p))
    {
        for (auto const& file : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(m_path)) {
            m_paths[file.path().string()] = std::filesystem::last_write_time(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::exception("Given path to watch is expected to be a regular file or directory");
    }
}

bool FileWatcher::contains(const std::string& key)
{
    auto el = m_paths.find(key);
    return el != m_paths.end();
}

void FileWatcher::start(const std::function<void(std::string, FileStatus)>& action) {
    m_watcher_thread = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(&action));
    while (m_running) {
       ... // WIP Check status of file and call action
    }
}

I initialize my watcher as follows:
config_watcher = std::shared_ptr<FileWatcher>(new FileWatcher{ "./config.json" , std::chrono::milliseconds(5000) });

and start it by calling (logger_spd is an std::shared_ptr to spdlog logger using a file sink)
config_watcher->start([](std::string path, FileStatus status) -> void {
    // Process only regular files, all other file types are ignored
    if (!std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::path(path)) && status != FileStatus::erased) {
        return;
    }
    switch (status) {
    case FileStatus::created:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(config_update_mutex);
        logger_spd->info("Configuration created");
        break;
    }
    case FileStatus::modified:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(config_update_mutex);
        logger_spd->info("Configuration modified");
        break;
    }
    case FileStatus::erased:
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(config_update_mutex);
        logger_spd->info("Configuration deleted");
        break;
    }
    default:
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(config_update_mutex);
        logger_spd->error("Unknown file status");
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(config_watcher->m_delay);
    }
);

The initial code is sub-optimal as mentioned in at least on of the comments below the article I have used as a source because of, among other issues, the std::this_thread::sleep_for() call inside the FileWatcher::start() that blocks the rest of the program unless instantiated in a separate thread. That is why I am trying to modify the code to act more as a typical worker thread, meaning that I would like to pass the action function (argument of FileWatcher::start()) to an underlying thread constructor and then manage everything inside the class.
I am having a problem to wrap my head around the forwarding the lambda to the underlying thread's constructor through the FileWatcher::start() function.

you should use std::make_shared rather than shared pointers constructor directly. And please post a [mcve].

Side note : using file system changes as a way to make multiple processes communicate with each other is very fragile. So I hope you're not using it for that ;)

@PepijnKramer No, I am using it to observe a configuration file for changes and reload it during runtime. Decided to add this feature since the starting of the debug session takes a long time (the main application alone is a couple of gigabytes as well as some of the deps such as libtorch that easily goes above 2GB) so my hope is to save on time developing other features. :D

You should not start the thread with the action, instead you should have a different function that contains the loop and which calls the action inside the loop and use that function for the thread.
Perhaps something like this:
void FileWatcher::start(const std::function<void(std::string, FileStatus)>& action) {
    m_watcher_thread = std::thread([action]() {
        while (m_running) {
            // Wait until something happens...
            action(file, status);
        }
    });
}

Note that I don't use a pointer for the thread object, as that's not needed.
The "sleep" should also be inside the loop, and not in the action function.

Thanks. So basically I am creating a lambda that captures the lambda that has been passed as an std::function instance. I reverted to the old code to use std::this_thread::sleep_for() inside the while(m_running) as you have suggested since it is indeed safer this way and also prevents an action to be provided that doesn't put the thread to sleep thus breaking this feature. In addition, I had to pass this to the second lambda (here [this, action]() { ... }) in order to make the FileWatcher's class members visible within that function.
